# Calculating and Passing number to another Activity

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, radio-button, calculator

I've to make an application in Android Studio that books a holiday. I've to display the price of the customers holiday depending on the type of accommodation they've chosen(3 radio buttons) and the number of nights they are staying(spinner). I've had many attempts to make the calculation and I have and while there seems to be no problem with it, the calculation result isn't passing through in to my other activity for me to display it. Can someone help me?

MakeBooking Activity

```
public class MakeBooking extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    Button hButton;
    Button reviewButton;
    Spinner parkSpin, nightSpin, adultSpin, sixteenSpin, fiveSpin;
    String radioAButtonSelected = "";
    String radioPButtonSelected = "";
     EditText fromDate;
     DatePickerDialog fromDatePickerDialog;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
     float cabinPrice = 45;
   float caravanPrice = 25;
     float tentPrice = 15;
   float Price, Price1;

    private static final String[] parks={" ","Lothianside Camping and Caravanning Park", "Loch Bannoch Touring Park", "Mckeowns Holiday Park"};
    String chosenPark ="not chosen";
    private static final String[] nights={" ", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14" };
    String chosenNights = "not chosen";
    private static final String[] adults={" ", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
    String chosenAdults = "not chosen";
    private static final String[] under16={" ", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
    String chosenSixteen = "not chosen";
    private static final String[] under5={" ", "0","1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
    String chosenFive = "not chosen";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_make_booking);

        parkSpin= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.parkSpinner);
        parkSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                parks);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        parkSpin.setAdapter(aa);

        nightSpin = (Spinner)  findViewById(R.id.nightSpinner);
        nightSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
       aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                nights);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       nightSpin.setAdapter(aa);

        adultSpin = (Spinner)  findViewById(R.id.adultSpinner);
        adultSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                adults);
            aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            adultSpin.setAdapter(aa);


       sixteenSpin = (Spinner)  findViewById(R.id.underSSpinner);
        sixteenSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
               under16);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sixteenSpin.setAdapter(aa);

        fiveSpin = (Spinner)  findViewById(R.id.underFSpinner);
        fiveSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                under5);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        fiveSpin.setAdapter(aa);



        hButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.homeButton);
        hButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        reviewButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bookButton);
        reviewButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.UK);


        findViewsById();

        setDateTimeField();



    }




    private void findViewsById() {
        fromDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fromDate);

        fromDate.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        fromDate.requestFocus();

    }

    private void setDateTimeField() {
        fromDate.setOnClickListener(this);

        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                fromDate.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            }

        },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));





    }

    public void onAccommodationClicked(View v) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) v).isChecked();
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.cabinRButton:
                if (checked)
                    radioAButtonSelected = "Cabin";
                Price = getCabinPrice(cabinPrice);
                break;
            case R.id.caravanRButton:
                if (checked)
                    radioAButtonSelected = "Caravan";
                Price = getCaravanPrice(caravanPrice);
                break;
            case R.id.tentRButton:
                if (checked)
                    radioAButtonSelected ="Tent";
                Price = getTentPrice(tentPrice);
                break;

        }
    }
    private float getCabinPrice(float cabinPrice) {
        return (Integer.parseInt(chosenNights) * cabinPrice);
    }

    private float getCaravanPrice(float caravanPrice) {
        return (Integer.parseInt(chosenNights) * caravanPrice);
    }

    private float getTentPrice(float tentPrice) {
        return (Integer.parseInt(chosenNights) * tentPrice);
    }

    public void onPetClicked(View v) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) v).isChecked();
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.yesRButton:
                if (checked)
                    radioPButtonSelected = "Yes";
                break;
            case R.id.noRButton:
                if (checked)
                    radioPButtonSelected = "No";
                break;


        }
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Toast.makeText(this, "clicked." + parent.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        switch (parent.getId()) {
            case R.id.parkSpinner:
                chosenPark = parks[position];
                break;
            case R.id.nightSpinner:
                chosenNights = nights[position];
                break;
            case R.id.adultSpinner:
                chosenAdults = adults[position];
                if (chosenAdults == "0"){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please confirm an adult over 21 is in your party.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.underSSpinner:
                chosenSixteen = under16[position];
                break;
            case R.id.underFSpinner:
                chosenFive = under5[position];
                break;
        }
    }


    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        chosenPark = "";
        chosenNights = "";
        chosenAdults = "";
       chosenSixteen = "";
      chosenFive = "";
    }


    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent;

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.homeButton:
                intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.bookButton:
                intent = new Intent(this, ReviewBooking.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }

        if(view == fromDate) {
            fromDatePickerDialog.show();
        }
        else {
            intent = new Intent(this, ReviewBooking.class);
            intent.putExtra("chosenPark", chosenPark);
            intent.putExtra("chosenNights", chosenNights);
            intent.putExtra("chosenAdults", chosenAdults);
            intent.putExtra("chosenSixteen", chosenSixteen);
            intent.putExtra("chosenFive", chosenFive);
            intent.putExtra("radioButtonSelected", radioAButtonSelected);
            intent.putExtra("radioPButtonSelected", radioPButtonSelected);
            intent.putExtra("fromDate", fromDate.toString());
            intent.putExtra("Price1", Price1);


            startActivity(intent);


        }
    }


}
```

Review Booking Acivity

```
public class ReviewBooking extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button hButton;
    float Price1;
    float cabin, caravan, tent;
    TextView radioChoice;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_review_booking);
        hButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.homeButton);
        hButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String uir = intent.getStringExtra("chosenPark");
        String uir2 = intent.getStringExtra("chosenNights");
        String uir3 = intent.getStringExtra("chosenAdults");
        String uir4 = intent.getStringExtra("chosenSixteen");
        String uir5 = intent.getStringExtra("chosenFive");
        String uir6 = intent.getStringExtra("radioAButtonSelected");
        String uir7 = intent.getStringExtra("radioPButtonSelected");
        String uir8 = intent.getStringExtra("fromDate");
        String uir9 = intent.getStringExtra("Price1");


        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.parkChoice);
        textView.setText(uir);

        TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nightsChoice);
        textView2.setText(uir2);

        TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.adultChoice);
        textView3.setText(uir3);

        TextView textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sixteenChoice);
        textView4.setText(uir4);

        TextView textView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fiveChoice);
        textView5.setText(uir5);

        TextView radioChoice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.radioChoice);
        radioChoice.setText(uir6);

        TextView petChoice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.petChoice);
        petChoice.setText(uir7);

        TextView dateChoice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateChoice);
        dateChoice.setText(uir8);

        TextView txtPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
        txtPrice.setText(uir9);

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);


    }
}
```

Comment: Also if anyone could get my date to pass through to the other activity as well that would be great haaha

Answer (score 1):

you can use intent.putExtraString to pass string. and similar method also available to pass integer long double.

Comment: I've done something to get the value 0.0 to pass through but it's not actually caclulating

Comment: On my booking activity when I do intent.putExtra("Price", String.valueOf(Price)); the value 0.0 is being passed to the other activity

Comment: it means your price is 0 in first activity. so that you are getting 0.0 in another activity. put debug point and check value of price before putting to extra field.

Comment: I debugged it but it doesnt seem to find anything wrong